# PHP Curl disable cache

Tags: php, caching, curl

I have a php script that periodically perform an http request to a remote api server.

I use curl to perform this task. My code is like the following exemple:

```
$url='http://apiserver.com/services/someservice.php?apikey='.$my_key;
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
    'Accept: */*',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
$data=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$json_data = json_decode($data,TRUE);
```

Recently I verified that it no longer fetch new data, it is using instead a cached version. I tried to add the following curl flags to the code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
```

This did not solve the problem. I still receive the same cached response.

If I add an extra parameter to the api url like "&time=".time(), that fix the problem, but I dont want to add extra parameters to the url.

What can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: cURL doesn't cache results. If the API server uses a CDN, then the CDN might be the cause.

Comment: The api server send an header like the following `Cache-Control: max-age=4000000`. Is possible to ignore that with curl and request a new page or the control is performed by the external server (that I have no control)?

Comment: Like I said, cURL doesn't cache anything. If you wanted to respect that header, you'd have to implement that yourself. If the external server uses a CDN, then the cached page gets served by the CDN and the only thing you can do, to get a new page, is by appending a random parameter (like `&time=".time()`). Since you've confirmed that this works, the CDN isn't configured to ignore query strings and serves a new page.